How to (partially) cross-divide 3D vectors?
A useful technique for vector cross-product:
It is often stated that there is no way to 3D cross-divide vectors, which is true, with caveats.
If we know that $ \vec{A} \times \vec{B} = \vec{C} $, and we know the value of $\vec{A}$ and $\vec{C}$, there are an infinite number of possible $\vec{B}$ vectors that satisfy $ \vec{A} \times \vec{B} = \vec{C} $.
The vector $\vec{B}$ can be always decomposed into a vector $\vec{B}_{parr}$ parallel to $\vec{A}$ ,
and a vector $\vec{B}_{p}$ perpendicular to $\vec{A}$.
$\vec{B}_{parr}$ contributes nothing to the value of $\vec{A} \times \vec{B}$.
$$ |\vec{B}_{p}| = |\vec{B}|sin(\theta) $$
$$ \vec{A} \times \vec{B} = \vec{A} \times \vec{B}_{p} $$
All vectors that can be expressed as $ \vec{B}_{p} + ( scalar * \vec{A} ) $ satisfy $ \vec{A} \times \vec{B} = \vec{C}$.
$$ \vec{A} \times  ( \vec{B}_{p} + (scalar * \vec{A} ) ) $$
$$ = \vec{A} \times \vec{B}_{p} + ( scalar * \vec{A} \times \vec{A} ) $$
$$ = \vec{A} \times \vec{B}_{p} $$

Given $\vec{A}$ and $\vec{C}$, the full exact solution set for $\vec{B}$ is $\vec{B}_{p} + ( scalar * \vec{A} )$ .
Given only $\vec{A}$ and $\vec{C}$, we cannot determine which $\vec{B}$ (from the solution set) generated $\vec{C}$, but we can determine the unique $\vec{B}_{p}$.
We can define "vector (partial) cross-divide"
$$ \vec{C}//\vec{A} \equiv (\vec{C}  \times  \vec{A})/(\vec{A} \cdot \vec{A}) = (\vec{C}  \times  \hat{A})/|\vec{A}| = \vec{B}_p$$
You can see this method produce useful results here:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_DkXD-cZLQE

derivation:
$$ |\vec{C}//\vec{A}|= |(\vec{C}  \times  \vec{A})/(\vec{A} * \vec{A})| $$
$$ |\vec{C}| = |\vec{A}||\vec{B}|sin(\theta) = |\vec{A}||\vec{B}_{p}| $$
$$ |\vec{C}//\vec{A}|= |(|\vec{B}_{p}||\vec{A}||\vec{A})/(|\vec{A}||\vec{A}|)| $$
$$ |\vec{C}//\vec{A}|= |(\vec{B}_{p})| $$
$\vec{C}//\vec{A}$ and $\vec{B}_{p}$ have identical length, are both perpendicular to both $\vec{C}$ and $\vec{A}$, and the right hand rule points them in the same direction.
$$ \vec{B}_{p} = \vec{C}//\vec{A} $$
Conversely, $ \vec{A}_{perpendicular} = - \vec{C}//\vec{B} $.
Proof by component appears as an answer below.

I’m voting to close this question because it is not about physics and also because there is no question.

Your definition has a typo. It should be $$\vec{C}//\vec{A} \equiv (\vec{C}  \times  \vec{A})/(\vec{A} \cdot \vec{A}) = (\vec{C}  \times  \hat{A})/|\vec{A}|^2 = \vec{B}_p$$
as there is $|A|^2$ in the denominator from the $A \cdot A$ product

I see that now, but it is tricky notation to do this. In the literature when I have seen this operator I see it as $$ \frac{ \vec{C}  \times  \vec{A} } {|\vec{A}|^2} $$

Here's a straightforward method that dispenses with explicit coordinates and relies only on a special case of the iterated cross product identity.
As in the question statement, given any solution $\require{cancel}{\bf B}$ of ${\bf A} \times {\bf B} = {\bf C}$, we can decompose uniquely ${\bf B} = {\bf B}_\parallel + {\bf B}_{\perp}$, where ${\bf B}_\parallel \parallel {\bf A}$ and ${\bf B}_\perp \perp {\bf A}$, and
$${\bf C} = {\bf A} \times ({\bf B}_\parallel + {\bf B}_{\perp}) = {\bf A} \times{\bf B}_{\perp}.$$
Now, crossing both sides with ${\bf A}$, say, on the right, gives
$${\bf C} \times {\bf A} = ({\bf A} \times {\bf B}_\perp) \times {\bf A} = {\bf B}_\perp ({\bf A} \cdot {\bf A}) - {\bf A} \cancelto{0}{({\bf A} \cdot {\bf B}_\perp)} = {\bf B_\perp} ({\bf A} \cdot {\bf A}) .$$ Provided ${\bf A} \neq {\bf 0}$, rearranging gives
$$\boxed{{\bf B}_\perp = \frac{{\bf C} \times {\bf A}}{{\bf A} \cdot {\bf A}}} .$$

Your answer is shorter, with elegant notation.
The point of my question-and-answer is that "we can (partially) divide vectors, and get a useful result", this technique exists, which is the opposite result to the prevailing posts in PhySe and MathSe. The proof-by-components is so that no one can refute the point.

Example where this equation is used (https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/682210/how-to-apply-a-screw-motion-for-this-case/682383#682383). Look for the definition of $\vec{\rm pos}$. It is used to find the point on a 3D line closest to the origin.

What are post(s) on math.se that misstate the result? It would be good to correct them. N.b. division has a precise meaning in the context of algebraic operations, and in that sense the cross product does not have a corresponding division operation: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_(mathematics)#Abstract_algebra

Travis, In saying "and MathSE", I overstated my case. I originally posted this in PhysicsSE, for deriving components of linear momentum from angular momentum
, they migrated it here.
PhysSE has a few posts like
(https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/111652/can-we-divide-two-vectors) where the accepted answer is "you cannot divide".
(I see one comment mentions finding the "component that's normal".)
I posted to simply explain what is possible, and why. I have not yet found a similar post on MathSE, asking or answering this issue.

Derivation by components:
$$ \vec{C}//\vec{A} \equiv (\vec{C}  \times  \vec{A})/(\vec{A} \cdot \vec{A}) = (\vec{C}  \times  \hat{A})/|\vec{A}| $$
$$ \vec{C} = \vec{A} \times  \vec{B}_{p}~(p~indicates~perpendicular)$$
$$ \vec{C} = ( A_y B_{pz} - B_{py} A_z , A_z B_{px} - A_x B_{pz} , A_x B_{py} - B_{px} A_y ) $$
$$ \vec{C}//\vec{A} = (( A_y B_{pz} - B_{py} A_z , A_z B_{px} - A_x B_{pz} , A_x B_{py} - B_{px} A_y )  \times  \vec{A})/(\vec{A} \cdot \vec{A}) $$
$$ \vec{C}//\vec{A} = (
A_z B_{px} A_z - A_x B_{pz} A_z + B_{px} A_y A_y - A_x B_{py} A_y ,
A_x B_{py} A_x - A_y B_{px} A_x + B_{py} A_z A_z - A_y B_{pz} A_z ,
A_y B_{pz} A_y - A_z B_{py} A_y + B_{pz} A_x A_x - A_z B_{px} A_x )
/(\vec{A} \cdot \vec{A}) $$
$$ \vec{C}//\vec{A} = ( xVal, yVal, zVal ) $$
consider x value alone:
$$ xVal=(A_z B_{px} A_z - A_x B_{pz} A_z + B_{px} A_y A_y - A_x B_{py} A_y ) / (\vec{A} \cdot \vec{A}) $$
$$ A_x A_x B_{px} - A_x A_x B_{px} = 0 $$
$$ xVal=(A_z B_{px} A_z - A_x B_{pz} A_z + B_{px} A_y A_y - A_x B_{py} A_y + A_x A_x B_{px} - A_x A_x B_{px}) / (\vec{A} \cdot \vec{A}) $$
$$ xVal= ( B_{px} (A_z A_z + A_y A_y + A_x A_x) - A_x (A_x B_{px} + A_y B_{py} + A_z B_{pz})) / (\vec{A} \cdot \vec{A}) $$
because $\vec{B}_p$ is perpendicular to $\vec{A}$:
$$ \vec{A} \cdot \vec{B}_{p} = A_x B_{px} + A_y B_{py} + A_z B_{pz} = 0 $$
$$ xVal= (B_{px}(A_z A_z + A_y A_y + A_x A_x)  - A_x*0) / (\vec{A} \cdot \vec{A}) $$
$$ xVal= B_{px}(A_z A_z + A_y A_y + A_x A_x) / (\vec{A} \cdot \vec{A}) $$
$$ xVal = B_{px} $$
$$ yVal = B_{py} $$
$$ zVal = B_{pz} $$
$$ \vec{C}//\vec{A} = ( B_{px}, B_{py}, B_{pz} ) $$
$$ \vec{C}//\vec{A} = \vec{B}_p $$
